# Как вывести только часть блоков?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем здравствуйте!

Необходимо первоначально при загрузке сайта на странице выводить только три блока `.related`, а при нажатии на блок `.add` выводить остальные семь блоков `.related`, и при этом блок `.add` прятать.

Возможно ли это сделать с помощью jQuery? Благодарю!

```css
.related {
display: block;
height: 30px;
width: 300px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
background-color: chocolate;
color: white;
}
.add {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="related">1 блок</div>
<div class="related">2 блок</div>
<div class="related">3 блок</div>
<div class="related">4 блок</div>
<div class="related">5 блок</div>
<div class="related">6 блок</div>
<div class="related">7 блок</div>
<div class="related">8 блок</div>
<div class="related">9 блок</div>
<div class="related">10 блок</div>
<div class="add">Показать остальные 7</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скройте в css все `.related`, кроме первых 3х и отображайте их по клику на `.add`, например, через `.show()`, а `.add`, соответственно, скрывайте через `.hide()`:

```js
$('.add').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.related').show();
});
```

```css
.related {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  color: white;
}

.block .related:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}

.add {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="related">1 блок</div>
  <div class="related">2 блок</div>
  <div class="related">3 блок</div>
  <div class="related">4 блок</div>
  <div class="related">5 блок</div>
  <div class="related">6 блок</div>
  <div class="related">7 блок</div>
  <div class="related">8 блок</div>
  <div class="related">9 блок</div>
  <div class="related">10 блок</div>
</div>
<div class="add">Показать остальные 7</div>
```